# Problema com <link rel="stylesheet/less" ... >

Tags: html, css, less

Eu vou começar a estudar LESS, mas o problema é que não consigo avançar para o primeiro passo.

Se eu colocar o `<link rel="stylesheeet/less"...>` não funciona. Só funcionar se eu colocar o `<link rel="stylesheeet"...>`  sem o `/less`.

Andei lendo e vi que poderia funcionar se eu rodasse em cima do WAMP. Mesmo assim não funcionou. Alguém já teve esse problema e pode me dar uma luz?

----- HTML -----

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.less">
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

----- CSS -----

```
body{
  background: url("imagens/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Você está testando sua página em um servidor ou abrindo direto o arquivo HTML?

Comment: Testei apenas pelo servidor local. WAMP. Direto pelo html, tb não funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido o problema!

Para isso:

Usar um compilador(não sei se é esse o nome) para o less.
Direcionar o  para o arquivo CSS que esse compilador vai gerar.

Aqui funcionou!

Estou rodando em cima do WAMP, não testei fora dele.

O  ficou assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/less.js"></script>
```

obs: O meu less.js, é o bootstrap.js renomeado.

Espero ter ajudado alguém.
Agradeço aos usuários que comentaram e tentaram me ajudar d alguma forma.
Grande abraço.
Bons estudos.

Comment: Sim, mas você na verdade contornou o problema. Compilar o LESS pra CSS é o recomendado em produção. A outra técnica (processar o LESS no cliente) é boa para desenvolvimento.

Comment: A maneira que fiz é errada/não recomendada? Porque foi a maneira que eu achei de fazer isso funcionar.

Comment: Não é errada, é a maneira que se deve usar em produção. Nesse caso, você nem precisa do JS do LESS, porque o arquivo já está compilado. Só dá um pouco mais de trabalho durante o desenvolvimento, já que precisa compilar antes de cada teste. Eu disse que você contornou porque não resolve o que você perguntou, que é interpretar o LESS dinamicamente no cliente (browser).

Comment: Minha esperança ainda é que funcione em um servidor online, mas ainda não deu pra fazer esses testes. Por enquanto, pra aprender a linguagem, acho que da pra quebrar o galho.

Comment: vai funcionar sim. Quando você compila o LESS localmente e manda linka o CSS no HTML, não tem mais LESS na jogada. Não tem por que não funcionar :)

Answer (score 5):

É importante lembrar que **os navegadores não entendem LESS nativamente!** Sendo assim, só adicionar o estilo em formato LESS à sua página não funcionaria mesmo. Para contornar isto você tem basicamente duas soluções:

#### Solução 1: Less.js

[Faça o download do LESS](http://lesscss.org/#download-options) e importe o arquivo `less.js` no seu projeto junto do seu arquivo `.less`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.less">
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Esta solução não é aconselhada para o ambiente de produção, já que toda vez que um usuário acessassar a sua página, o JavaScript teria que interpretar e compilar seu arquivo `.less` em tempo de execução.

#### Solução 2: Compilar o LESS em CSS

Seguindo a [documentação do projeto](http://lesscss.org/#using-less), com o Node.js instalado, você poderia usar a seguinte linha de comando para compilar seu arquivo:

```
$ lessc caminho/para/meu/arquivo/estilo.less
```

Você também pode utilizar uma [interface gráfica](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=compile+less+app) caso não seja familiarizado com o terminal.

Comment: Eu estou usando o SublimeText3. Achei em um dos tutos que vi, recomendam instalar o node.js e no sublime, alguns plugins que permitem q o próprio Sublime faça essa compilação.

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa [baixar](https://github.com/less/less.js/archive/master.zip) e incluir o interpretador de LESS em JavaScript para isso funcionar:

```
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Referência:** http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage

Comment: bfavaretto,obrigado pela resposta.

Fiz o que você disse. Baixei e fiz o link referente ao less.js. Mas ainda não funcionou. Dei mais uma testada e continua igual. Se tirar o /less, tudo funciona.
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.less">
  <script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: De fato, fui testar e vi o mesmo. Se tiver novidades, atualizo aqui.

Comment: Também li que no Chrome, não funciona.Apesar de ter estranhado isso, fui testar no FFox e no IE. Mesmo problema!
Não faço ideia do que pode ser.

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o **[grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)** ou **[gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)**
ambos podem garantir a compilação do seu less e várias outras coisas importantes como garantir que seu código está escrito de forma correta. É algo simples mais poderoso, além de compilar seu less, você pode concatenar ou minifica-los.

Comment: Estou compilando direto pelo Sublime. Algum plugin(não sei exatamente qual dos que instalei), está fazendo compilando pra mim.

Answer (score 0):

Para isso você precisa baixar o download [less.js](https://github.com/less/less.js/archive/master.zip) e incluí-lo em um   tag no elemento  da sua página:

```
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

- Certifique-se de incluir suas .less *antes* do script acima.
- Quando você vincula mais de uma .less cada uma delas é compilada de forma independente, ou seja, qualquer variavel, mixins ou namespaces que você define em uma não são acessiveis em outra.

Comment: A ordem das tags está certinha. Já havia me atendado para isso tb.