# Less deve ser compilado ainda em desenvolvimento?

Tags: less

Minha dúvida surgiu após [ler essa pergunta e suas respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43540/problema-com-link-rel-stylesheet-less).

Muitas IDEs fornecem modos de compilar o código LESS ainda em desenvolvimento. No Netbeans, por exemplo, é possível configurar para sempre que o código `.less` for salvo, ser compilado e gerado o CSS. Nos projetos que preciso utilizar algum pré-processador eu crio uma estrutura semelhante a esta:

```
/assets
  /style
    /css
    |  style.css
    /less
      /build
         style.less
      | variables.less
      | mixins.less
```

Sempre que o código do diretório *style/less/build* for salvo, automaticamente um arquivo `.css` é criado em */style/css*.

Então, no HTML basta referenciar o local em que se encontra as folhas de estilos, exemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style/css/style.css"/>
```

Pra mim essa seria a melhor forma, ao invés de deixar esse processamento ser feito no dispositivo *client* que precisaria:

1. Baixar o arquivo LESS
2. Baixar o script que compila esse código (suponha que tenha vários outros scripts a serem baixados também)
3. Compilar o código e transformar em CSS
4. Apresentar o CSS

Estou a pouco tempo usando LESS, mas só vejo essa prática sendo vantajosa se por ventura um arquivo LESS for mais leve que um CSS (e olhe lá).

---

Então, minhas dúvidas:

- Um arquivo `.less` é mais "leve" que um `.css`?
- Quando compilar o código no computador do usuário é a melhor escolha?
- Que benefícios/malefícios tenho ao optar por compilar o `.less` do
  lado cliente?

Comment: Ótimas respostas.
Só gostaria de acrescentar mais uma informação que talvez seja útil.
Como foi citado o NetBeans e o e Grunt, quero cityar o SublimeText, que com os plugins certos instalados, também compila o LESS a cada SAVE(Ctrl+S).
Não sei exatamente qual faz isso, mas instalei os seguintes plugins para trabalhar com o LESS no Sublime: **Lessc** **Less-Build** **Less2Css** **SublimeOnSaveBuild**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compilar o arquivo Less enquanto em desenvolvimento é opção do programador. Eu prefiro compilar (grunt faz isso sozinho para mim). Portanto, mesmo em desenvolvimento, utilizo o CSS, e não os arquivos Less. Em produção, sem dúvidas deve ser distribuído o arquivo CSS, e não o Less.

Respostas às suas perguntas individuais:

**1.** Um arquivo Less não é mais leve do que um CSS pois precisa ser compilado.

**2.** Não. Pode ser que o browser do usuário se quer suporte arquivos em Less e então seu site seria exibido "quebrado".

**3.** Acredito que nenhum benefício. Para malefícios, veja itens *1* e *2*.